# "error: cannot find symbol" when building Chromium for Android with new classes

Tags: java, android, chromium

I need to create a custom OmniboxResultsAdapter (org.chromium.chrome.browser.omnibox) for Chromium for Android. If I edit existing classes, everything is fine, but if I add new classes (for example, empty MyClass with no fields or methods) and try to use it in code (e.g., MyClass myObject = new MyClass()) and try to make a build with:

```
 chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Release chrome_public_apk
```

I get:

```
    ../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/omnibox/LocationBarLayout.java:1430: error: cannot find symbol
            MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
            ^
      symbol:   class MyClass
      location: class LocationBarLayout

    ../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/omnibox/LocationBarLayout.java:1430: error: cannot find symbol
            MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
                                   ^
      symbol:   class MyClass
      location: class LocationBarLayout
    2 errors

    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I suppose the compiler cannot find the class because of ProGuard.

What files do I need to modify to get the right result?

Answer (score 2):

The java class of Chromium is declared in file `src/chrome/android/java_sources.gni`. You need to add the file path of MyClasst to that file like this:

```
"java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/MyClass.java"
```